# How do I set CryptoTokenExtension to work under HTTP for development work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get U2F to work under Chrome. I'm developing so I'd like it if I could connect to my local web server with not HTTPS certificate.

I am running Chrome in OSX

Currently my workflow is

- Quit all instances of Google Chrome.
- Restart Google Chrome with the --show-component-extension-options command-line flag.
- Navigate to chrome://extensions and enable Developer Mode by clicking a checkbox in the top right corner.
- Find the CryptoTokenExtension extension.
- Click on "background page". This will open a Developer Tools window, including a Console.
- In the console, type:

  HTTP_ORIGINS_ALLOWED = true;

and it still doesn't work. What step am I missing

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the value won't reregister the [extension's manifest.json](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/cryptotoken/manifest.json?l=27&rcl=f8bc6c6e82a4890587bd6f664711c2ce248514e0) which has to be patched too:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": [
    "https://*/*"
  ],
```

You can manually edit resourse.pak file in any binary/hex editor (not a text editor).
In Windows it's usually in %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\xxxxx\resources.pak

1. Backup the file
2. Find `"fjajfjhkeibgmiggdfehjplbhmfkialk"`
3. Replace the nearby `"https://*/*"` with     `"*://*/*"`
4. Optionally edit HTTP_ORIGINS_ALLOWED
5. Save and restart Chrome

You can automate this by writing a simple patcher in node.js or any other scripting language.

P.S. Not tested.